# Vetor para JTextField

Tags: java, swing

Tenho que somar 43 campos de textos que o usuário irá preencher os que irão ser utilizados para ter um total e esse total será utilizado em minha fórmula e não consegui achar uma solução para reduzir essas linhas que fiz manualmente atribuindo a uma variável cada campo. A minha pergunta é:

Consigo elaborar um Vetor para receber campos de textos assim? como seria a fórmula para pegar um Jtext e pegar o valor do próximo e ir somando?

Comment: O que é um JText?E adicione um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar e executar seu código.

Comment: JTextField, acabei abreviando por costume, trata-se de um campo de texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um loop em todos os componentes do seu painel e se caso ele seja uma instância de `JTextField`, você soma. Ex:

```
Double total = 0.00;    

for (Component c : painel.getComponents()) {    
    if (c instanceof JTextField) {
        total += Double.parseDouble(((JTextField) c).getText());
    }
}
```

Mas lembre-se que todos seus `JTextField` utilizados no cálculo devem estar no mesmo painel.

Comment: Zulian, era JTextField mesmo, desculpa, acabei abreviando por costume, mas valeu cara, irei testar no meu código aqui, só o "System.out.println" que vou precisar mesmo, porque essa variável total eu uso na fórmula.

Comment: Só tem uma problema, pelo que entendi de seu código, você está criando um jTextField a cada rodada do for, mas eu já criei todos os que preciso na tela do jFrame, só quero pegar os valores e somar agora, ai tem o seu segundo for, mas não sei como ele vai passar de um nome para o outro, sendo que cada jText meu são diferentes o nome da variável.

Comment: @GabrielCardoso, o `System.out.println()` era só pra visualizar o resultado.    Dessa maneira que coloquei é mais prática, mas como você já criou, vou atualizar a resposta, dando outro exemplo.

Comment: @GabrielCardoso atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Entendi, foi o que imaginei, de qualquer forma eu teria que atribuir os 43 manualmente na lista, foi praticamente o que eu fiz atribuindo a uma variável. Colocar aqui um pedaço do código. 

double TotalCC = 0;

        //Somar os valores passados no centro de custo.
        TotalCC += Double.parseDouble(spnCC1.getValue().toString());
        TotalCC += Double.parseDouble(spnCC2.getValue().toString());
        ...
Mas queria uma forma simplificada de somar isso tudo sem ter que atribuir cada um na mão, porque imagina se eu tivesse muito mais campos..

Comment: @GabrielCardoso sem você apresentar um [mcve] vai ficar dificil ajudar mesmo. A resposta responde ao que foi perguntado, está começando a desvirtuar da duvida inicial, e tudo porque você está apresentando informações que deveriam ter sido adicionadas na pergunta, e não como comentários, fora a não apresentação de um exemplo executável do seu código.

Comment: Postei um pedaço ai do código que estou utilizando no momento, são 43 linhas iguais a essa para cada campo de exceto, eu só queria fazer isso dentro de um for sem precisar atribuir cada campo, o que você me passou realmente funciona, mas eu de qualquer forma irei atribuir cada campo na hora de adicionar na lista. Queria ver se algum método passava por todos jText no painel e ia somando eles.

Comment: @GabrielCardoso se você não quer manipular todos os campos, a solução já foi dada usando loop. Agora se você não está sabendo adicioná-lo no seu código, já é outro problema, e para isso, você **deve** apresentar um **[mcve]** se quiser obter algo mais especifico pra sua solução.

Comment: Você que não entendeu até agora que meu problema é não querer setar isso tudo manualmente, mas relaxa cara, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Na última solução que coloquei, pegando os componentes do painel, você não precisa setar manualmente, olhe novamente e tente entender.

Comment: @GabrielCardoso a solução está no final da resposta, no ultimo laço, ele vai resgatar todos os componentes de texto do painel. Qual a dificuldade? É só aplicar no seu código.

Comment: @Zulian pra não confundir o autor, seria interessante remover o resto, já que aparentemente a outra solução inicial não servirá pra ele.

Comment: Agora apareceu a edição pra mim, vou testar essa, eu estava até então falando da solução anterior.

Comment: Zulian, muito obrigado cara, deu certinho, criei um painel, joguei todos os controles giratórios lá dentro(agora estou usando JSpinner) e fiz a fórmula, funcionou perfeitamente, valeu galera o apoio. Se alguém souber algum documento bom das funcionalidades de Swing, to tomando um pal aqui pra editar o layout dele. Desde já agradecido.

Comment: @GabrielCardoso Que bom que foi útil. Para os layouts, recomendo ler [a documentação oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Você pode marcar a resposta como correta, clicando no **V** ao lado da mesma.

Comment: Show de bola cara, marquei sim, obrigado pelo documento.