# Acessar JLabels sem utilizar switch...case

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo com `JLabel` de 1 a 50, consigo acessa-las em linha de código sem ter que usar um switch.

Vocês podem verificar que o que muda no código e só o `lblBoard1` ou `lblBoard2` e assim por diante, quem vai determinar o `JLabel` eh a variável `points`.

Não existe problema no código abaixo, somente gostaria de usar algo como (vou inventar pois eh exatamente isto que quero) `lblBoard[points].setIcon`. Mais um detalhe como criei estes `JLabel` em tempo de desenho não vi como criar um array deles na interface do netBeans. O que tenho realmente são JLabel's terminando com números `lblBoard1`, `lblBoard2` e assim por diante.

```
 switch (points){
        case 1:{
            if (samePlace){
                lblBoard1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay12) ) ));
            } else {
                if (player == "Player 1"){
                    lblBoard1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay1) ) ));
                } else {
                    lblBoard1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay2) ) ));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            if (samePlace){
                lblBoard2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay12) ) ));
            } else {
                if (player == "Player 1"){
                    lblBoard2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay1) ) ));
                } else {
                    lblBoard2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay2) ) ));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            if (samePlace){
                lblBoard3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay12) ) ));
            } else {
                if (player == "Player 1"){
                    lblBoard3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay1) ) ));
                } else {
                    lblBoard3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imagePlay2) ) ));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
```

Caso elucide mais a questao esta eh a tela do meu jogo. queria ir movimentando os players casa por casa. esta funcionado fazendo o swicth porem eh codigo que nao acaba mais. 51 Labels.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual problema você esta tendo ? `switch case` não há necessidade de abrir e fechar `{}` pois já existe o `break`.

Comment: talvez nao tenha sido claro, nao tenho problema de codigo. Gostaria de usar algo como lblBoard[i].setIcon para me ajudar a nao ter que fazer o switch case.

Comment: mesmo assim obrigado pela dica...

Comment: Por favor forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possível  testar o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples que vejo é trabalhar com um array de *JLabels* e depois acessar apenas o índice do `JLabel` desejado, usando a variável `points`. Mas pra isso, você precisará mexer direto no código, e não no construtor de telas do netbeans.

Instancie um array de labels no começo do seu código:

```
JLabel[] labelBoards = new JLabel[51];
```

Você pode usar um loop para iniciar, configurar e preencher cada um deles na sua tela:

```
for(int i = 0; i < labelBoards.lenght; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    // aqui voce configura o label do jeito que precisar
    labelBoards[i] = label;

}
```

E depois pra acessar, basta ter em mente que a variável `points` representará a posição do `JLabel` desejado no array:

```
if (samePlace){
    labelBoards[points].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(imagePlay12))));
} else {
    if (player == "Player 1"){
        labelBoards[points].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(imagePlay1))));
    } else {
        labelBoards[points].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(imagePlay2))));
    }
}
```

Lembrando que, se `points` é incrementada em outro lugar, não precisaria de laço neste caso, apenas este trecho ser chamado cada vez que ela mudar de valor.

Atente-se apenas de que, apesar de ter 51 `JLabels` no array, os índices vão de 0 a 50, portanto, a variável `points` só poderá ter valores apenas dentro desse range, senão vai estourar exceção `ArrayIndexOfBoundException`.

---

Há uma outra forma, aplicando a dica [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240648/28595), que consiste em pegar os componentes e filtrar quando for uma instancia de `JLabel` e colocá-los num `ArrayList` ou num array mesmo, com sua tela já criada do jeito que está agora, mas no seu caso, fazer isso seria um *workaround* bem ridículo, pois seria o mesmo que criar um remendo de código para arrumar outro código mal planejado. O recomendado seria a solução com array mesmo, daria mais trabalho mas ao menos seu código fica melhor com a lógica melhor organizada.

Sem mais detalhes fica dificil sugerir outra solução que não seja com array, se não conseguir implementá-la, edite a pergunta e forneça um [**exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que seja possível ver o código funcionando e sugerir algo alternativo.

Comment: Obrigado @Articuno. Pelo que entendi não existe a opção que gostaria. Tenho que fazer a criação dos jLabels por linha de código. Não sei qual é mais fácil, criar uma dificuldade no início para desenhar a tela ou se desenhar via netBeans tratar sem ser array. Mesmo assim muito obrigado, realmente é o que eu havia pensado, não existe solução para quando se cria via desenho no netBeans. (Digo isso por que é muito mais fácil desenhar via netBeans do que via código, que tenho que determinar a posição, tamanho, todas as características de cada um dos jLabels e não é nada visual). Muito obrigado.

Comment: @AdrianoMenezes há outras formas sem precisar de array, mas voce precisaria alterar sua tela de qualquer jeito. Se apresentar seu codigo na forma de um [mcve] eu posso ver se é possivel sugerir algo em cima do seu codigo.

Comment: como sou iniciante tenho duvida de como fazer completo (imaginei que era completo kkk) são três .java tem como eu postar eles?

Comment: @AdrianoMenezes para fazer um exemplo minimo, completo e verificavel você deve isolar somente o problema. No seu caso, voce provavelmente vai ter que criar um novo projeto somente com a tela e a disposicao dos labels do seu projeto principal. Acesse o link que nele explica direitinho como fazer.